# Updating action on express server every short peroid of time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ethereum

I'm currently developing a gambling website built on top of Ethereum blockchain. Since recording all the bets made by a gambler is very complex (because they can make a bet without even visiting the website, by interacting directly with the blockchain) I came to conclusion that I need a function on my server that will run every 0.5 - 1 minute and download all the new bets that came up from the blockchain and shadow them in my database (yes I need to have them in my database as well).

I am not experienced too much with all this backend stuff, I've read somewhere that I could use setInterval(30 seconds) function on the server and run it on the server start. But is this a real option? Do people even do things like this? Won't an infinite function running every 30 second just clog up the whole server?

Comment: Using setInterval is fine to use in this scenario. Why would it clog up the whole server?

Comment: Because I perform an asynchronous action on server every 30 seconds 24/7, I thought.

Comment: If this function does not 'leak' memory in any way it should be able to run indefinitely. Looking at your description you should be fine since you request data and then write it to a database. The data is not retained in process memory.

Comment: That's great, thanks buddy for clearing it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done similar a number of times with no issue. Events will just be queued and run as appropriate. However, one thing to be wary of:

```
const timeout = 1000;
setInterval(() => {
    // some process that takes longer than timeout
}, timeout);
```

When you write something like this, setInterval will run again after the timeout period even if the first operation hasn't completed yet. THIS can easily lead to you blocking your thread. Instead, I prefer to use setTimeout to achieve this:

```
const timeout = 1000;
const withTimeout = () => {
    // some process that takes longer than timeout
    setTimeout(withTimeout, 1000);
}
```

This way, your second invocation of withTimeout is only queued up AFTER the first execution is run. With this mechanism, you don't get your operations strictly every **timeout** period, but rather **timeout** AFTER the last one.